# Tensorflow EPOCH how to grab information

Tags: python-3.x, string, tensorflow, command-line

So if I run my tensorflow 2.0 code through my python UI, I can see the epochs printing out to the command line. How can I 'get or access' that information (preferably while its running) so I can put the string in a text field.

I know its the what is making the output

```
model.fit(......)
```

I am using pyqt5 for my GUI and would like to set the text of a textfield to what the model.fit shows (preferably while its running) that way the output to command line and my text field are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea is to access the loss during the training, not only at the end of the training. What if you train for 200 epochs and 5h per epoch? The answer above is a suitable one provided that the programmer only wants to check at the end of the training, not at the end of each epoch during the training.

The lines below will solve this issue:

```
class LossHistoryCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

  def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    #logs['loss'] or logs['val_loss'] (the latter available only if you use validation data when model.fit()
    # Use logs['loss'] or logs['val_loss'] for pyqt5 purposes

    print('Loss is: logs['loss'], validation loss is: logs['val_loss']')





model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=64,
          epochs=10,
          steps_per_epoch=5,
          verbose=1,
          callbacks=[LossHistoryCallback()])
```

In this way, you can get the output of your loss and validation_loss at the end of each epoch, not only at the end of your training, since you want to track the progress of the training at each epoch not to see the result only at the end.

Answer (score 0):

To access the loss at each epoch, you can use `history = model.fit(...)` instead of `model.fit(...)`. This saves the loss information at each epoch into a `keras.callbacks.callbacks.History` object, where the loss can be retrieved and printed. You can further add more information to history by tinkering with `keras.callbacks.callbacks`, here's some documentation for reference: https://keras.io/callbacks/

Here is what you could do to print the loss at each epoch:

```
history = model.fit(...)
loss_history = history.history["loss"] #type is list
for i in range(len(loss_history)):
    print("Epoch %i :"%i, loss_history[i])
```